# Optimize Function - use array as input

Tags: python, scipy, least-squares

I am playing with SciPy today and I wanted to test least square fitting. The function malo(time) works perfectly in returning me calculated concentrations if I put it in a loop which iterates over an array of timesteps (in the code "time").

Now I want to compare my calculated concentrations with my measured ones. I created a residuals function which calculates the difference between measured concentration (in the script an array called conc) and the modelled concentration with malo(time).

With `optimize.leastsq` I want to fit the parameter PD to fit both curves as good as possible. I don't see a mistake in my code, malo(time) performs well, but whenever I want to run the `optimize.leastsq` command Python says "only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars". If I set the timedt array to a single value, the code runs without any error.

Do you see any chance to convince Python to use my array of timesteps in the loop?

```
import pylab as p
import math as m
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize


Q = 0.02114
M = 7500.0
dt = 30.0
PD = 0.020242215
tom  = 26.0 #Minuten
tos = tom * 60.0 #Sekunden
timedt = np.array([30.,60.,90])
conc= np.array([ 2.7096,  2.258 ,  1.3548,  0.9032,  0.9032])


def malo(time):
     M1 = M/Q
     M2 = 1/(tos*m.sqrt(4*m.pi*PD*((time/tos)**3)))
     M3a = (1 - time/tos)**2
     M3b = 4*PD*(time/tos)
     M3 = m.exp(-1*(M3a/M3b))

     out = M1 * M2 * M3
     return out

def residuals(p,y,time):
    PD = p
    err = y - malo(timedt)
    return err

p0 = 0.05

p1 = optimize.leastsq(residuals,p0,args=(conc,timedt))
```

Comment: What's the shape of `err`? Generally, you should supply a self-contained example, which we can run for testing. Here, it would be helpful to have example values for all the important variables.

Comment: @David: I attached a self-contained example. How do I get the shape of 'err'?

Comment: @BenjaminMewes `Daten` is not defined. Maybe just `conc` instead of `Daten.conc`?

Comment: @RicardoCárdenes you're totally right. was a relict from the complete script ;) I changed that.

Comment: The shape of a numpy array can be accessed using the `shape` property., i.e. `print err.shape`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that you're working here with arrays defined in NumPy module. Eg.

```
timedt = np.array([30.,60.,90])
conc= np.array([ 2.7096,  2.258 ,  1.3548,  0.9032,  0.9032])
```

Now, those arrays are not part of standard Python (which is a general purpose language). The problem is that you're mixing arrays with regular operations from the `math` module, which **is** part of the standard Python and only meant to work on scalars.

So, for example:

```
M2 = 1/(tos*m.sqrt(4*m.pi*PD*((time/tos)**3)))
```

will work if you use `np.sqrt` instead, which is designed to work on arrays:

```
M2 = 1/(tos*np.sqrt(4*m.pi*PD*((time/tos)**3)))
```

And so on.

NB: SciPy and other modules meant for numeric/scientific programming know about NumPy and are built on top of it, so those functions should all work on arrays. Just don't use `math` when working with them. NumPy comes with replicas of all those functions (`sqrt`, `cos`, `exp`, ...) to work with your arrays.

Comment: Thank @Ricardo Cardenes for that clarification on NumPy! I am switching from R to Python. So every information data types and structures is highly welcome for me :)

Comment: If you're coming to Python from R, you probably want to have a look at  [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org), [StatsModels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net), and so on :)

Comment: I am already looking at Pandas - Thanks for StasModels, I will watch this as well!